# Write regex for pattern like W00001

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am new to Regular Expressions and any help is highly appreciated.

- Pattern like W00000,W00001,W00002,W00004
- Must begin with W
- Each string before comma must be six characters
- String can only be repeated four times
- Comma in between
- Must not begin or end with comma

I tried below pattern and some others, like `(^[W]{1}\d{5}){1,4}')`, and none of them work correctly:

```
Select 'X' from dual Where REGEXP_LIKE ('W12342','(^[W]{1}\d{5})(?<!,)$')
```

Comment: i think theres no need to use [W]{1} ... it could simply be W

Comment: Yes...using a character class with a single character is redundant, and using `{1}` as a quantifier is *always* redundant.

Comment: +1 Seeing a new user post an attempt they tried on their own instead of just saying "GIVE ME A REGEX THAT DOES THIS!" is so refreshing.

Comment: If your question has been adequately answered, please [mark the answer that you feel best addressed your question as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Once you have at least 15 rep, you can also [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the accepted answer and any other answers you found useful.

Comment: @Walls Because of the nature of regex, I tend to have more flexible standards in this tag for what I expect to see from the OP in terms of attempts to solve the problem, because often knowing what to try is knowing how to do it (and I've seen others express the same sentiment); but I think this question illustrates the value of showing attempted solutions anyway: The attempted regex helped me understand some things about what he wants to accomplish that would have been unclear from just the verbal description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the OP is saying the match should *fail* if the string begins or ends with a comma, not just that the preceding or trailing commas shouldn't match, so anchors are needed. Also, based on the regex he attempted, I infer that a single group, such as `W00000`, should match. So, I think the regex should be this, if the characters following the **W** must always be digits:

```
^W[:digit:]{5}(,W[:digit:]{5}){0,3}$
```

Or this, if they can be something other than digits:

```
^W[^,]{5}(,W[^,]{5}){0,3}$
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The OP posted the following comment:

> I am on Oracle 11g and [:digit:] doesn't work. When I replace it with [0-9] it then works fine.

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS1012), Oracle 11g conforms to the POSIX regex standard and *should* be able to use POSIX character classes such as **[:digit:]**. However, I noticed in the docs that Oracle 11g does support Perl-style backslash character class abbreviations, which I didn't think was the case when I originally wrote this answer. In that case, the following should work:

```
^W\d{5}(,W\d{5}){0,3}$
```

Comment: Actually, one point that needs to be clarified...I'm inferring from the attempted regex posted in the question that this pattern should be the *entire* string. If you're trying to match the pattern described within a larger string, then the anchors should be replaced with negative zero-length assertions. Please let me know if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Adi, Your assumptions were correct..I have tested this and it's is what I was looking for. Though for some reason [:digit:] wasn't working for me and I used [0-9] and it's worked fine...Your assumption about the condition that W need to followed by 5 digits was correct..:)

Thank you everyone..Now I know a bit of RegEx.

Answer (score 2):

Well in that case, you can do this:

```
(W[^,]{5},){3}W[^,]{5}
```

Comment: Your initial `W.` should also be `W[^,]`, if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: From one of its pattern, I think it could be from one to 4 string blocks. Your expression will only find the 4 blocks version.

Comment: @JustinMorgan, yeah. After the edit, the question was *more* clear. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Amit Joki!! I forgot to mention there will be at least one block of W12345 and may be followed by three and I added {1,3} to your RexEx. When I add comma in the beginning or end, it doesn't work Select 'X' from dual Where REGEXP_LIKE (',W12342,W12342,W12342,','(W[^,]{5},){1,3}W[^,]{5}') 'W12342,W12342,W12342,W12342'- Works 'W12342,W12342,W12342' - works

Comment: @user3561229 Just to verify that I understand correctly: You say here "When I add comma in the beginning or end, it doesn't work"; I take it you mean that it "doesn't work" in that if you add a comma at the beginning or end, this regex still matches the string (not including the preceding and/or trailing commas), and you want it to not match at all in that case?

Comment: Thanks Amit Joki for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this should do it!

```
^W[0-9]{5}(,W[0-9]{5}){0,3}$
```

One `W12345` pattern, maybe followed by one to 3 `,W12345` blocks.

Edit1: Adding ^$ to fail if there is a comma
Edit2: Fix class, since it fails on Oracle 11g

Comment: Thanks Mat M., I tried and it's not giving correct output with a string 'W12342,W12342,W12342,W12342'. Also, when I add comma in the beginning or end, it doesn't work either. Select 'X' from dual Where REGEXP_LIKE ('W12342,W12342,W12342,W12342','(W[:digit:]{5})(,W[:digit:]{5}){1,3}')

Comment: Three issues: (1) I believe he wants the match to fail if there is a preceding or trailing comma, not just exclude them from the match. (2) I believe a single group of **W** plus six characters (digits?) should match, so the quantifier at the end should be `{0,3}`. (3) The first set of  parentheses isn't needed.

Comment: @Adi: 1.& 2. Fixed  3. Agree. will fix if another edit comes :)

Comment: @user3561229: which Oracle version do you use ? Could you try on a 4-block that `W[:digit:]{5},W[:digit:]{5},W[:digit:]{5},W[:digit:]{5}` works. [Oracle 10g doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm#i690819) says digit class is legit and so is `{}` construct, so it should work. Maybe there is an issue elsewhere.

Comment: Okay...though I already posted that. I was just explaining why I didn't think the regex you had was what the OP was looking for.

Comment: Mat M, I am on Oracle 11g and [:digit:] doesn't work. When I replace it with [0-9] it then works fine.

Comment: @MatM No problem...I just didn't want anyone to think I was repeating a previous answer and flag me, because after the edit the answers were almost identical.

Comment: @user3561229 That's odd, according to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS1012) the **[:digit:]** class *should* work. However, I'm seeing that 11g [does support the \ classes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS235), so try `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. Let me know if it works and I'll update the answer.